# MediaServer remote binder Camera object died - only on KITKAT

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working with SurfaceView and using [this](https://github.com/davidgatti/dgCam) source code, but whenever i take back to back images, getting:

```
mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
Camera service died!
Camera Error 100
```

And Log says:

```
    11-06 12:11:49.691: I/Choreographer(18462): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 12:11:49.692: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:50.372: I/View(18462): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=76.10486, y[0]=153.67984, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9951837, downTime=9951837, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:50.386: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:50.445: I/View(18462): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ...P..I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=76.10486, y[0]=153.67984, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9951911, downTime=9951837, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:50.445: V/Provider/Settings(18462): get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
11-06 12:11:50.446: V/Provider/Settings(18462):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-06 12:11:50.679: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:51.768: D/Camera-JNI(18462): Allocating callback buffer
11-06 12:11:51.770: I/CameraFramework(18462): handleMessage: 256
11-06 12:11:51.845: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:52.439: I/View(18462): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{41e14cb0 VFED..C. ......I. 0,240-160,480 #7f050006 app:id/ibUse}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=78.10242, y[0]=71.35135, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9953906, downTime=9953906, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:52.462: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:52.513: I/View(18462): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{41e14cb0 VFED..C. ...P..I. 0,240-160,480 #7f050006 app:id/ibUse}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=78.10242, y[0]=71.35135, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9953980, downTime=9953906, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:52.513: V/Provider/Settings(18462): get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
11-06 12:11:52.513: V/Provider/Settings(18462):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-06 12:11:53.231: I/Choreographer(18462): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 12:11:53.233: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:53.707: I/View(18462): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=69.11365, y[0]=142.7027, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9955171, downTime=9955171, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:53.716: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:53.777: I/View(18462): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ...P..I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=69.11365, y[0]=142.7027, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9955243, downTime=9955171, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:53.778: V/Provider/Settings(18462): get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
11-06 12:11:53.778: V/Provider/Settings(18462):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-06 12:11:54.024: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.250: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.267: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.284: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.306: I/View(18462): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.00378, y[0]=477.00623, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9960766, downTime=9960766, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:59.307: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.337: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.353: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.370: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.385: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.408: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.424: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.446: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.468: I/View(18462): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{41dfb4a8 VFED..C. ...P..I. 0,0-160,480 #7f050003 app:id/ibCapture}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.00378, y[0]=477.00623, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9960921, downTime=9960766, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
11-06 12:11:59.473: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:11:59.483: V/Provider/Settings(18462): get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
11-06 12:11:59.483: V/Provider/Settings(18462):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-06 12:12:05.897: D/IPCThreadState(18462): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x544888c8
11-06 12:12:05.897: W/CameraBase(18462): Camera service died!
11-06 12:12:05.897: D/IPCThreadState(18462): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x544888c8
11-06 12:12:05.905: D/IPCThreadState(18462): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x54488bd0
11-06 12:12:05.905: W/CameraBase(18462): mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
11-06 12:12:05.906: D/IPCThreadState(18462): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x54488bd0
11-06 12:12:05.935: I/Choreographer(18462): Skipped 387 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 12:12:05.936: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:12:05.957: D/dalvikvm(18462): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x54ba5000
11-06 12:12:05.959: D/dalvikvm(18462): init ref table
11-06 12:12:05.960: D/dalvikvm(18462): init mutex
11-06 12:12:06.032: I/CameraFramework(18462): handleMessage: 1
11-06 12:12:06.034: E/CameraFramework(18462): Error 100
11-06 12:12:06.035: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:12:06.185: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:12:06.264: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:12:06.294: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
11-06 12:12:06.311: I/SurfaceView(18462): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
```

CameraPreview.java:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mHolder.setFixedSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

}
```

My device supports Android Kitkat, So may I know exactly where I am doing - what i am missing. Why I am getting this issue ?

Comment: Not Sure, But `setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder.getSurface())` will work for you

Comment: @Amy where i have to try this in class, i am already using mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);

Comment: @Sonali have you managed to find the solution or the reason for this behaviour ?